# Can iOS framework Bundle another framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode6

I was working with an open source framework called Mobfox.I am attaching its Screenshot.It contains many other open source framework.Is it possible to bundle these all framework into one (MobFox.framework).So that projects using MobFox.framework need not want to download other frameworks for making their project run. [image]